# Canvas glitches when hardware acceleration is on

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm desperate.

I have to debug at work a canvas animation that glitches when hardware acceleration is activated on firefox running on windows.

I've searched all over the internet and have no idea how I can fix this.

That I understood is that hardware (gpu) acceleration is used when rendering outside the visible window. Can someone confirm that ?

Here is an example of the glitch, the images are piling up instead of translating :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2QCb.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJ39T.png

Comment: Are you asking if GPU acceleration is used to render what you can't see?

Comment: Yes, it's something that I read and I'm asking for confirmation.

Comment: I've never heard that - GPU acceleration would be used for what you **CAN** see. and yes, firefox with some video hardware = glitch

Comment: Why would the canvas render something that isn't inside of the canvas width and height? I'm sure it would just hold the position and not render it. But can you please explain what you mean by "glitches"? What is happening to the animation?

Comment: It's hard to really help with so few informations. Any code to show or a fiddle? What kind of glitches? What about other browsers? What are you drawing on the canvas?

Comment: I'm drawing a first image : http://i.imgur.com/wtwi8nV.png and then translate a second image but the first image stays in place : http://i.imgur.com/cPvzcIn.png

Comment: Can't you just do some kind of workaround? Save current Canvas, resize it which forces it to clear the canvas and place the image again?

Comment: @chado "but the first image stays in place" - why wouldn't it? unless you clear the canvas all rendering stays. if you translate and redraw an image it doesn't mean the previous drawing of it disappear. if you need to render things that move around / animate, you probably want to clear the canvas and redraw all your objects every animation step. in games for example, usually there's an endless loop using requestAnimationFrame() that every frame first clear the canvas and then render all the visible objects.

Comment: I am using the requestAnimationFrame() function that clears the canvas. Everything else works fine in the animation.

Comment: I've found the solution.

It seems that when you use hardware acceleration on firefox and internet explorer on windows, the image you are drawing may be multiplied.

The solution I found is to add transparent space on the left and right of the image.